# Why 'rbp' of a frame is not matching 'rsp' of previous frame?

Tags: c, x86-64, stack-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
funcB(int *ret)
{
    int x = 10;
    x += *ret;;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

int
funcA(int x, int y)
{
    int ret = 0;
    ret = x + y;
    funcB(&ret);
    ret += 10;
    return ret;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int ret;
    ret = funcA(10, 20);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

As per the assembly instruction, I was expecting that 'rbp' of `funcB()` will be the same as 'rsp' of `funcA()`. But that is not the case. Looks like 'rbp' of `funcB` is changed somewhere? Why is it so?

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005a6: file tmp.c, line 26.
(gdb) b funcA
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400572: file tmp.c, line 15.
(gdb) b funcB
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400539: file tmp.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /nobackup/ibhattac/code/./a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at tmp.c:26
26          ret = funcA(10, 20);
(gdb) info reg rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdd00   0x7fffffffdd00
(gdb) info reg rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffdd10   0x7fffffffdd10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, funcA (x=10, y=20) at tmp.c:15
15          int ret = 0;
(gdb) info reg rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdcd0   0x7fffffffdcd0
(gdb) info reg rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffdcf0   0x7fffffffdcf0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, funcB (ret=0x7fffffffdcec) at tmp.c:6
6           int x = 10;
(gdb) info reg rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdca0   0x7fffffffdca0
(gdb) info reg rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffdcc0   0x7fffffffdcc0  >>> Why this is not same as 'rsp' of funcA()
```

Does 'rsp' of `funcA()` change to make space for `push %rbp` and the return instruction counter?

Does that mean `leaveq` in `funcB()` modifies `rbp` and only then load it to `rsp`?

```
(gdb) disassemble funcB
Dump of assembler code for function funcB:
   0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp   
   0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>:     mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400539 <+12>:    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400540 <+19>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400544 <+23>:    mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x0000000000400546 <+25>:    add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
=> 0x0000000000400549 <+28>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040054c <+31>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x000000000040054e <+33>:    mov    $0x400670,%edi
   0x0000000000400553 <+38>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400558 <+43>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000040055d <+48>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400562 <+53>:    leaveq
   0x0000000000400563 <+54>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: You can see it in the disassembly. Before `mov %rsp,%rbp`, there is a `push %rbp` which subtracts 8. And of course there was the `callq` from teh caller, which subtracts another 8.

Comment: @RaymondChen Got it. Thank you.